# Virtual PC/Server software intalled on SBS 2011 Essentials that hosts other Windows OS?

Tags: virtualization, windows-sbs-2011

I'd like to know if anyone else has successfully installed Oracle Virtual Box, VMware Workstation, or Virtual PC 2007 software on SBS 2011 Essentials that hosts other Windows OS without causing any harm to the SBS?  SBS 2011 Essentials doesn't allow Hyper-V to be installed because of it being a Domain Controller.

If you did, what product did you use and did you have to do any workarounds to get it to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Nothing can really _safely_ run an end of life operating system.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Don't want to do it, but I need to be able to share files off the SBS 2011 server with a DOS 6.22 system that only has NETBEUI protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would consider deploying a desktop level machine as a secondary server before I used VirtualBox on SBS2011.  Neither is ideal, but the desktop is, IMHO, "less bad."